# HTML- Center Image on page and have div float left with out changing page center of logo

Tags: html, css

I am trying to do something, I have searched the forums and have been browsing the web for 4+ hours. I have also done a lot of trial and error with many different ways to do it but they did not do as I am trying to do. I removed all my trial and errors and left the code minimal.

I want the logo centered on the page not centered in the area that is left only after the float left is applied.

Here is a live demo of the site:
[http://rissew.com/](http://rissew.com)

Here is what i am trying to do:
[WireFrame - What i want to look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6tebk.jpg)

Maybe float is not the correct way to do it. That is why i have turned to the people here.

```css
@charset "UTF-8";  


html {
    font-family: sans-serif;
}

body {
    margin: 0
}

a {
    color: #B90000;
    text-decoration: none;
}
a:focus,
a:hover {
    color: #15c;
    outline: 0
}
a:hover {
    color: #15c
}

*,
:after,
:before {
    box-sizing: border-box
}

body {
    font-family: "Titillium Web Regular", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    line-height: 1.42857143;
    color: #4d4d4d;
    background-color: #f1f1f1;
    overflow-x: hidden
}

.header {
    background: #fff;
    position: relative;
    box-shadow: 0 10px 10px -6px rgba(0, 0, 0, .1)
}

.header .container {
    padding-left: 0;
    padding-right: 0;
    width: 100%
}

.nav {
    background-color: #fff;
    border-top: 2px solid #f6f6f6;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 2
}

.nav:after,
.nav:before {
    content: "";
    display: table
}

.nav:after {
    clear: both
}

.navlist {
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: center
}

@media screen and (min-width:767px) {
    .page-nav__list {
        width: 767px
    }
}

@media screen and (min-width:989px) {
    .navlist {
        width: 989px
    }
}
@media screen and (min-width:1199px) {
    .navlist {
        width: 1200px
    }
}

.page-nav__item {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0 5px;
    display: block;
    width: 16.666666667%;
    line-height: 1;
    float: left
}

.navlink {
    font-size: .75rem;
    font-family: "Titillium Web Semibold", "Open Sans Bold", "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-weight: 400;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    letter-spacing: .05em;
    color: #666;
    padding: 10px 0;
    display: block;
    border-bottom: 3px solid #ccc
}

.navlink:focus,
.navlink:hover {
    color: #B90000;
    border-color: #B90000
}

.navlink.active {
    color: #B90000;
    border-bottom: 3px solid #B90000
}

.sociallink{
    display: block;
}

.sociallist {
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0;
    max-width: 1450px;
    margin-top: 0;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
}

.sociallist li {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    margin-left: 5px;
    margin-right: 5px;
    display: inline-block
}

.youtube{
    display: block;
    height: 26px;
    width: 26px;
    background-image: url('http://www.rissew.com/assets/images/youtube.png');
    background-size: contain;
    text-indent:-9999px;
}

.youtube:hover {
     background-image: url('http://www.rissew.com/assets/images/youtubehover.png');
}

.facebook{
    display: block;
    height: 26px;
    width: 26px;
    background-image: url('http://www.rissew.com/assets/images/facebook.png');
    background-size: contain;
    text-indent:-9999px;
}

.facebook:hover {
     background-image: url('http://www.rissew.com/assets/images/facebookhover.png');
}

.twitch{
    display: block;
    height: 26px;
    width: 26px;
    background-image: url('http://www.rissew.com/assets/images/twitch.png');
    background-size: contain;
    text-indent:-9999px;
}

.twitch:hover {
     background-image: url('http://www.rissew.com/assets/images/twitchhover.png');
}

.twitter{
    display: block;
    height: 26px;
    width: 26px;
    background-image: url('http://www.rissew.com/assets/images/twitter.png');
    background-size: contain;
    text-indent:-9999px;
}

.twitter:hover {
     background-image: url('http://www.rissew.com/assets/images/twitterhover.png');
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
 <head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title>Rissew Gaming - Where the Frag Happens</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/css/style.css" />
        <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="32x32" href="media/favicon-32x32.png">
 </head>
    <body>
  <header id="header" class="header">
            <ul class="sociallist">
              <li class="youtube"><a href="https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCyNi8D-XcpZnZAQVlzQj2RQ" class="sociallink">youtube</a></li>
              <li class="facebook"><a href="http://www.facebook.com/RissewGaming" class="sociallink">facebook</a></li>
              <li class="twitter"><a href="http://www.twitter.com/RissewGaming" class="sociallink">twitter</a></li>
              <li class="twitch"><a href="http://www.twitch.tv/Rissew" class="sociallink">twitch</a></li>
            </ul>        
            <img class ="headerbig" source="assets/images/headerbig.png"alt="Rissew Gaming">
          <nav class="nav">
            <ul class="navlist">
              <li class="page-nav__item"><a href="index.html" title="" class="navlink active">Home</a></li>
              <li class="page-nav__item"><a href="about.html" title="" class="navlink">About</a></li>
              <li class="page-nav__item"><a href="guides.html" title="" class="navlink">Guides</a></li>
              <li class="page-nav__item"><a href="forum.html" title="" class="navlink">Forum</a></li>
              <li class="page-nav__item"><a href="shop.html" title="" class="navlink">Shop</a></li>
              <li class="page-nav__item"><a href="watch.html" title="" class="navlink">Watch</a></li>
            </ul>
          </nav>
  </header>
        
        <main>
        </main>
        <footer>
            <p>
            </p>
        </footer>
    </body>
```

Comment: What should happen when the links does not fit left side of the logo?

Comment: Not sure what you are trying to achieve here

Comment: Question deleted as comment was being typed: your question about not understanding how to pass the "entire JComboBox" is unclear. It's an object, just like any other object, and its reference may be passed from one class to another the same as you would for any other reference type, such as via a method or constructor parameter.

Comment: Also, I never accused you of asking for code, but you will want to show your code attempts with your questions, best if an [mcve], so we can run it, and see exactly where and how you're stuck.

Answer (score 2):

May be this is what you are looking for i hope.

add `float:left` to `.sociallist` as

```
.sociallist{
    float: left;
}
```

and style `.headerbig` as

```
.headerbig {
    display: block;
    max-width: 120px;
    float: none;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
}
```

Comment: I would suggest including the use of `clear` in your answer if you're going to suggest `float`, however I don't think this is a good use-case for `float`, personally.

Comment: I tried that but it centers it based off of the available space It pushes more right than what the middle of page would be. I want the logo center in the middle of the page and the socialist to be to the left.    I uploaded site to rissew.com and you can see what i mean.

Comment: I think you achieved it ryt

Answer (score 0):

What I would suggest is changing your `.sociallist` to be `position: absolute; left: 0;` so that it sticks to the left side regardless of other elements. You can then put a width on your `.headerbig` and set it to `margin: 0 auto;` so that it is centered.

```
.headerbig {
    display: block;
    width: 120px; /* YOUR IMAGE WIDTH HERE */
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.sociallist {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
}
```

---

```css
@charset "UTF-8";  


html {
    font-family: sans-serif;
}

body {
    margin: 0
}

a {
    color: #B90000;
    text-decoration: none;
}
a:focus,
a:hover {
    color: #15c;
    outline: 0
}
a:hover {
    color: #15c
}

*,
:after,
:before {
    box-sizing: border-box
}

body {
    font-family: "Titillium Web Regular", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    line-height: 1.42857143;
    color: #4d4d4d;
    background-color: #f1f1f1;
    overflow-x: hidden
}

.header {
    background: #fff;
    position: relative;
    box-shadow: 0 10px 10px -6px rgba(0, 0, 0, .1)
}

.header .container {
    padding-left: 0;
    padding-right: 0;
    width: 100%
}

.headerbig {
    display: block;
    width: 120px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.nav {
    background-color: #fff;
    border-top: 2px solid #f6f6f6;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 2
}

.nav:after,
.nav:before {
    content: "";
    display: table
}

.nav:after {
    clear: both
}

.navlist {
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: center
}

@media screen and (min-width:767px) {
    .page-nav__list {
        width: 767px
    }
}

@media screen and (min-width:989px) {
    .navlist {
        width: 989px
    }
}
@media screen and (min-width:1199px) {
    .navlist {
        width: 1200px
    }
}

.page-nav__item {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0 5px;
    display: block;
    width: 16.666666667%;
    line-height: 1;
    float: left
}

.navlink {
    font-size: .75rem;
    font-family: "Titillium Web Semibold", "Open Sans Bold", "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-weight: 400;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    letter-spacing: .05em;
    color: #666;
    padding: 10px 0;
    display: block;
    border-bottom: 3px solid #ccc
}

.navlink:focus,
.navlink:hover {
    color: #B90000;
    border-color: #B90000
}

.navlink.active {
    color: #B90000;
    border-bottom: 3px solid #B90000
}

.sociallink{
    display: block;
}

.sociallist {
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0;
    max-width: 1450px;
    margin-top: 0;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
}

.sociallist li {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    margin-left: 5px;
    margin-right: 5px;
    display: inline-block
}

.youtube{
    display: block;
    height: 26px;
    width: 26px;
    background-image: url('http://www.rissew.com/assets/images/youtube.png');
    background-size: contain;
    text-indent:-9999px;
}

.youtube:hover {
     background-image: url('http://www.rissew.com/assets/images/youtubehover.png');
}

.facebook{
    display: block;
    height: 26px;
    width: 26px;
    background-image: url('http://www.rissew.com/assets/images/facebook.png');
    background-size: contain;
    text-indent:-9999px;
}

.facebook:hover {
     background-image: url('http://www.rissew.com/assets/images/facebookhover.png');
}

.twitch{
    display: block;
    height: 26px;
    width: 26px;
    background-image: url('http://www.rissew.com/assets/images/twitch.png');
    background-size: contain;
    text-indent:-9999px;
}

.twitch:hover {
     background-image: url('http://www.rissew.com/assets/images/twitchhover.png');
}

.twitter{
    display: block;
    height: 26px;
    width: 26px;
    background-image: url('http://www.rissew.com/assets/images/twitter.png');
    background-size: contain;
    text-indent:-9999px;
}

.twitter:hover {
     background-image: url('http://www.rissew.com/assets/images/twitterhover.png');
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
 <head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title>Rissew Gaming - Where the Frag Happens</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/css/style.css" />
        <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="32x32" href="media/favicon-32x32.png">
 </head>
    <body>
  <header id="header" class="header">
            <ul class="sociallist">
              <li class="youtube"><a href="https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCyNi8D-XcpZnZAQVlzQj2RQ" class="sociallink">youtube</a></li>
              <li class="facebook"><a href="http://www.facebook.com/RissewGaming" class="sociallink">facebook</a></li>
              <li class="twitter"><a href="http://www.twitter.com/RissewGaming" class="sociallink">twitter</a></li>
              <li class="twitch"><a href="http://www.twitch.tv/Rissew" class="sociallink">twitch</a></li>
            </ul>        
            <img class ="headerbig" source="assets/images/headerbig.png"alt="Rissew Gaming">
          <nav class="nav">
            <ul class="navlist">
              <li class="page-nav__item"><a href="index.html" title="" class="navlink active">Home</a></li>
              <li class="page-nav__item"><a href="about.html" title="" class="navlink">About</a></li>
              <li class="page-nav__item"><a href="guides.html" title="" class="navlink">Guides</a></li>
              <li class="page-nav__item"><a href="forum.html" title="" class="navlink">Forum</a></li>
              <li class="page-nav__item"><a href="shop.html" title="" class="navlink">Shop</a></li>
              <li class="page-nav__item"><a href="watch.html" title="" class="navlink">Watch</a></li>
            </ul>
          </nav>
  </header>
        
        <main>
        </main>
        <footer>
            <p>
            </p>
        </footer>
    </body>
```

Comment: Doing it this way makes it centered like i want but then it makes the social list always be to the left even when the page is open very large. it does not let the width stay with the 1450px i set.

Comment: @Ken If you put `position: relative;` on the parent of `sociallist`, it will stay locked to the left edge of that container instead without having an effect on the other elements. I would suggest using this technique.